# Include restrictions as attribute

Tags: xml, xsd, restriction

I have a question: Is it possible to set a restriction as an attribute? E.g.:

```
<xs:element name="test">
 <xs:complexType>
  <xs:sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
    <xs:element name="elem1" type="xs:integer" minInclusive="0" maxInclusive="3"/>
    <xs:element name="elem2" type="type="xs:normalizedString" minlength="1" maxlength="7"/>
  </xs:sequence>
 <xs:complexType>
<xs:element>
```

It seems not to work, but I have a lot of "elems(x)" and I want to avoid to define for each one sympletype including restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible the way you've depicted; what you could do instead is to define a global (named) simple type that captures the constraints that you want, and then reference that where you want it, just like you do with the built-in types.

```
<xsd:simpleType name="tt">
   <xsd:restriction base="xsd:normalizedString">
      <xsd:minLength value="1"/>
      <xsd:maxLength value="7"/>
   </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>


<xsd:element name="elem2" type="tt"/>
```